# How to convert a Postgresql timestamptz to a Javascript Date?

Tags: javascript, string, postgresql, date, timezone

My database creates a bunch of timestamptz values using the `now()::TEXT` function. In several API calls I receive these values, but I'm having difficulty turning them into Javascript Date objects.

Here's an example of a Timestamptz string that Postgres returns: `2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00`

The problem is that if I try to do `new Date("2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00")`, then there's finicky behavior in the browser. It looks like I have to append a "Z" first to the string to get the time correct (because of timezones?)

Also, Firefox doesn't seem to parse it at all (but Chrome does). If I remove the "+00", it seems to work.

So I came up with this "solution" which seems to work on both browsers, but I have to call it on all my dates before working with them, and it seems kinda brittle. Is this the proper way?

```
function fixDate(date) {
  return date.replace("+00", "") + "Z";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported formats for the built–in parser are described in [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), essentially a specific subset of ISO 8601 and the format specified for [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring). Parsing of any other format (that is, anything that doesn't match **exactly** with one of the specified formats) is implementation dependent and should not be trusted.

You might consider parsing the string and constructing a new string that is compliant with ECMA-262, e.g. convert "2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00" to "2019-09-12T09:52:52.992+00:00".

```js
// Convert 2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00 to
//         2019-09-12T09:52:52.992+00:00
// Assumes all strings are +00:00
function rectifyFormat(s) {
  let b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[0] + '-' + b[1] + '-' + b[2] + 'T' +
         b[3] + ':' + b[4] + ':' + b[5] + '.' +
         b[6].substr(0,3) + '+00:00';
}

let s = '2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00';
console.log(new Date(rectifyFormat(s)))
```

However, also heed the general advice to avoid the built–in parser, even with supported formats. It also seems inefficient to parse a string to produce another string that is then parsed again to produce a Date. It's preferable to write your own parse function (a couple of lines of code) or use a library, e.g.

```js
// Parse string like '2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00'
// to a date
// Assumes string is always +00
function myDateParse(s) {
  let b = s.split(/\D/);
  --b[1];                  // Adjust month number
  b[6] = b[6].substr(0,3); // Microseconds to milliseconds
  return new Date(Date.UTC(...b));
}

let s = '2019-09-12 09:52:52.992823+00';
console.log(myDateParse(s).toISOString());
```